# Postgres data types integer and boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a sql table (version 9.3 PostgreSQL) with fields (tour character varying, tourtime int)... I want to write a query like `case when tour = 'A' then tourtime = 2 when tour = 'B' then tourtime = 3 else 0` etc..

However i get the error

> CASE types integer and boolean cannot be matched

Why is this?

Comment: Cast boolean as integer? tourtime::int4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your CASE you have tree branches:

```
 case when tour = 'A' 
        then tourtime = 2 
      when tour = 'B' 
        then tourtime = 3 
      else 0
 end
```

In the first two, you have boolean expressions (`(tourtime = 2)` and `(tourtime = 3)`), which are `true` or `false` according to the value of the column `tourtime`. In the third one, you have an integer expression (`0`).

When the system tries to infer the type of the result it matches the three types and found that they are different.

So you should have either all integer expressions, or boolean expressions, depending on what you want as result.

Comment: You are missing `END` in your case.